# HTML Head element not properly registering on w3.org validator?

Tags: html, css, validation, w3c-validation

I'm learning html and my instructor told us to use the w3.org html validator to help check code. I'm working with a simple web page to start and it all displays fine but when I put it into the validator, it gives errors and I'm completely stumped.

The start of my code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- Html is the element but tag is html + the open/close tags-->
<head>
<title> Around the World Music </title>
<img src="worldmusiclogo.jpg" alt="Around the World Music logo" title="Around the World Music Logo" >
<style>
h1 {
color: red;
}
h2 {
color: orange;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
....rest of code
```

The validator output is

```
Info: The Content-Type was text/html. Using the HTML parser.

Info: Using the schema for HTML with SVG 1.1, MathML 3.0, RDFa 1.1, and ITS 2.0 support.

Error: Element style not allowed as child of element body in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

From line 12, column 1; to line 12, column 7

Logo" >↩↩↩<style>↩h1 {↩

Contexts in which element style may be used:
    If the scoped attribute is absent: where metadata content is expected.
    If the scoped attribute is absent: in a noscript element that is a child of a head element.
    If the scoped attribute is present: where flow content is expected, but before any other flow content other than inter-element whitespace and style elements, and not as the child of an element whose content model is transparent.
Content model for element body:
    Flow content.

Error: Stray end tag head.

From line 20, column 1; to line 20, column 7

↩</style>↩</head>↩↩<bod

Error: Start tag body seen but an element of the same type was already open.

From line 22, column 1; to line 22, column 6

↩</head>↩↩<body>↩<!--T
```

It seems the problem is the validator interprets some code as the end of the head before `<style>`. Thus it thinks style is in the wrong place, `<body>` and then my `</head>` and `<body>` tags are extraneous. Can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

`<img>` cannot be a descendant of `<head>`—remove that element or move it to `<body>`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an `img` in the `head`, if you want to set a favicon try using :

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="logo.png" />
```

in the `head`